# Accessible custom modals in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, accessibility, voiceover

I'm trying to make a custom modal view in SwiftUI be more accessible with VoiceOver.

I've set `.accessibility(addTraits: .isModal)` but VoiceOver till focus elements under the modal. So then I tried to set `.accessibility(hidden: true)` when the modal is visible. That kind of works, but VoiceOver focus the element closest to the position of the button that opened the modal, but it would be more logical to focus the first element in the modal.

Not sure how to solve this and what the best way forward is.

Gist with code for popup.

https://gist.github.com/tfsjohan/80e9e39287f65fc044222468b834d74b

Answer (score 0):

What it worked for me was to set `.accessibilityElement(children: .ignore)` to the sibling views and sending `UIAccessibility.post(notification: .screenChanged, argument: nil)` before presenting the popup.
In that way, the components behind the popup aren't available anymore during the navigation, and the screen change event moved the focus of the voice over to the element with the highest priority.